# Run function for each element separately?

Tags: jquery

How do I run a function for each element separately?

So if I click on the first `open` only the first group should open.

```js
    $(document).on('click', "a.showdetails", function () {
      $( ".group" ).toggleClass( "opened" );
    });
```

```css
.option{
  width: 200px;
}

.showdetails{
  display: block;
}

.group{
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

.group.opened{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="option">
  <a href="#" class="showdetails">open</a>
  <div class="group"></div>
</div>

<div class="option">
  <a href="#" class="showdetails">open</a>
  <div class="group"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use clicked element context to find its sibling element with class group:

```
var groupelements = $('.group');
$(document).on('click', "a.showdetails", function () {
  var targetgroup = $(this).next('.group');
  groupelements.filter(targetgroup).removeClass( "opened" )
  targetgroup.toggleClass( "opened" );
});
```

NOTE: You have used event delegation here. You should only use it if elements `a.showdetails` are loading dynamically. else use `.click` to bind the click for static element.

Comment: Do you know how to close the active group if  a other group gets opened?

Comment: Using [JQuery method .next()](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=next) can be a problem when you change the HTML element placement. But getting element by the parent container is a good practice.

Comment: @hmd: is that the reason for downvote? OP did not mentioned the part of modification to DOM. you should not be assuming that part.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar A programmer or a solution provider should always think about the Best and Bad cases. So, when you're giving some solution you should be at your best place what are you giving to someone! :)

Comment: @hmd: if we try covering all best cases then will have to write whole article about the solution... :) . like for this, using `.parent()` , `.siblings()`, `.closest()` etc. Issue was to point him to use dom traversing along with clicked object.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar bro, you are right but at least we should care about what kind of problem an OP can face at the moment. Thanks for you time! :)

Comment: @hmd: No problem. i was curious as i was not expecting downvote for that :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the parent first for the Clicked `Anchor`. Using Jquery `.next()` can be a problem when you change the HTML element placement. But getting element by the parent container is a good practice.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="option">
      <a href="#" class="showdetails">open</a>
      <div class="group">hello 1</div>
    </div>

    <div class="option">
      <a href="#" class="showdetails">open</a>
      <div class="group">hello 2</div>
    </div>
```

Javascript/JQuery:

```
$(function() {

      $( ".showdetails" ).click(function() {
        // Getting Parent of clicked Anchor
        var parent_option = $(this).closest('.option');
        // Toggle class to the child .group class element.
        $( ".group", parent_option ).toggleClass( "opened" );    
      });

    });
```

**CSS:**

```
.option{
      width: 200px;
    }

    .showdetails{
      display: block;
    }

    .group{
      display: none;
      width: 200px;
      height: 100px;
      background: #f2f2f2;
    }

    .group.opened{
      display: block;
    }
```

**WORKING DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ha97tmjf/